# ASP.NET Click event does not work for multi buttons what created in tab button control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in ASP.NET and I have a problem..

In my code, btn.Click event does not work for multi buttons what created in tab button control.  Can you guys advice me?
Thanks,

```
<asp:Button Text="TAB MENU" BorderStyle="None" ID="Tab" CssClass="Initial" runat="server" OnClick="Tab_Click" />

<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Direction="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:Panel>




protected void Tab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     foreach (...) {

            Button btn = new Button();                        
            btn.Click += Button1_Click;
            panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            **some code here! but does not work.**
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to add details of what exactly you're trying to achieve here.  It looks like you want to dynamically add buttons to a panel when a user clicks on a tab, is that right?  Because if that's the case, there may be a better way to do it (for example, if the buttons are the same every time, why not do it in the prerender event of the page instead of the tab click event), but without more info on what you're trying to do there, it's difficult to say.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, MajorRefactoring! Yes, it is. When user clicks on a tab, buttons will add to a panel dynamically. all button's id and text are different and also  count of buttons are different on every tabs. When user clicks a button on a tab, popup window will be opened for a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably lies along the lines of the fact that the button does not exist when the Button1_Click callback is fired...  Asp.net webforms is a somewhat leaky abstraction over HTTP, and therefore it's a bit tough to decipher sometimes, but I expect what is happening is that when the postback from your button click occurs, the button doesn't actually EXIST in the control tree, because that button only gets added to the control tree when a tab control is clicked.  So because the button does not exist on the postback, webforms doesn't know what to do with the event, so it ignores it...

If your buttons must be created dynamically, consider making them do some javascript to edit some hidden field or something, the value of which you can inspect in the Page_Load method, and then do whatever you want to do functionality-wise with that value.

If they are NOT dynamic, and instead will be the same for each page load (but different for each tab - ie, when the page is loaded, you're drawing some info from a db to decide what buttons to display, but that will not change from postback to postback of the same page), then consider creating the buttons in the Page_Load event instead of inside the event that is raised when the tab is created.

ALTERNATIVELY, since in your comment you suggest that the buttons will be used to open a new window, why not just make the buttons do that client side, ie with javascript window.open commands.  Then you don't even need to postback to the server at all...

Comment: Thank you for all your help, MajorRefactoring!  Now I understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Button btn = new Button(); 
btn.Click  += new RoutedEventHandler(Button1_Click);
panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: Hi, Claudio.  I tried it but it does not work for me.  Thank you for your help.